# Syntax error, unexpected keyword_end in method with if/elsif conditions

Tags: ruby

Why does this code have `error unexpected keyword_end`?

```
class Mars_Rover
    def numeric?
        Float(self) != nil rescue false
    end
    puts "Enter the details"
    response = gets("\t\n")
    word=response.split(/\n/)
    $i=1
    for $i in 1..(word.length) 
        m=word[$i].split(//)
        if m[0].numeric?
            $x=Integer(m[0])
            $y=Integer m[1]
            $dir= m[2]
        else
            $k=0
            for $k in 0..(m.length-1)
                if $dir=="N"
                    if m[$k]=="L"
                        dir="W"
                        break
                    elsif m[$k]=="R"
                        dir="E"
                        break
                    else
                        y++
                    end
                end  

                elsif $dir=="S"
                    if m[$k]=="L"
                        dir="E"
                        break
                    elsif m[$k]=="R"
                        dir="W"
                        break
                    else
                        y--  
                    end
                end  

                elsif $dir=="E"
                    if m[$k]=="L"
                        dir="N"
                        break
                    elsif m[$k]=="R"
                        dir="S"
                        break
                    else
                        x++ 
                    end
                end      
                else
                    if m[$k]=="L"
                        dir="S"
                        break
                    elsif m[$k]=="R"
                        dir="N"
                        break
                    else
                        x--  
                    end
                end 
            end
        end            
    end
end
```

Comment: Your code asked me to be refactored. Consider using switch/case statements, they are powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to close each `elsif` with an `end` (which you do on the condition `if $dir=="N"`), they simply chain and there should be just one `end` to match the starting `if`